# Oracle VBAscript connection error

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

```
Dim strDBDesc As String
strDBDesc = "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ##)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ##)))"
cn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & strDBDesc & ";User ID=##;Password=##;"
                                           
query1 = ""
query1 = ERM.Sheets("query").Range("A10")
query1 = Replace(query1, "v_job_name", v_field1)
                    
'Set OraDynaSet = objdatabase.DBCreateDynaset(query1, 0&)
Dim OraDynaSet As ADODB.Recordset
                    
Set OraDynaSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
OraDynaSet.ActiveConnection = cn
OraDynaSet.Open query1, cn, adOpenStatic
```

I am getting error message as ORA-00933 sql command not ended properly

Error Message

[image]

### Query 1

```
select 
job_name,Status
 from (
select  Distinct  a.job_name,
          a.description description,Decode (job_type,98,'Box',99,'Command Job',102,'File watcher job',job_type) job_type,
      substr(decode(d.status,1,'Running',
                             3,'Starting',
                             4,'Success',
                             5,'Failed',
                             6,'Terminated',
                             7,'On Ice',
                             8,'Inactive',
                             9,'Activated',
                             11,'On Hold',
                             12,'Que Wait',
                             d.status),1,9) status,
a.mach_name,a.owner,g.command,g.std_err_file,g.std_out_file,f.days_of_week,f.start_times,f.start_mins,f.run_calendar,f.max_run_alarm,profile
     from AEDBADMIN.ujo_job a,
          AEDBADMIN.ujo_job_runs c,
          AEDBADMIN.ujo_job_status d,
          (select joid,max(STARTIME) startime,
                  max(endtime) endtime
             from AEDBADMIN.ujo_job_runs group by joid) e,
             AEDBADMIN.ujo_command_job g,
            AEDBADMIN.ujo_sched_info f
    where a.joid  =  c.joid(+)
      and a.joid  =  d.joid(+)
      and a.joid  =  e.joid(+)
      and a.joid  =  f.joid(+)
      and a.joid  =  g.joid(+)
      and (c.startime = e.startime or c.startime is null)
      and job_name ='v_job_name'// job name replaces 
      and a.is_active =1
);
```

Comment: I am getting error message as ORA-00933 sql command not ended properly. can you please tell me any what is wrong in my connection string

Comment: i am getting error on this command -OraDynaSet.Open query1, cn, adOpenStatic

Comment: What is the query string? Try `Debug.Print query1` in order to get it.

Comment: the query would be little big , how do i post it here ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - i ahve posted my code here . please let me know the issue in code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this one

```
and job_name ='v_job_name'// job name replaces
```

In SQL comments are done by `-- ...` (single line) or `/* ... */` (multi line).

However, perhaps ADODB does not support comments at all, I recommend to remove it entirely.

Or it is the semicolon `;` at the end - remove it.

Just a note, you should rewrite your query and use ANSI join syntax instead of old Oracle join syntax - especially for OUTER JOINS.

Comment: -i tried by changing the query but still it doesn't get my output results . can you please help me in the connection string of VBA to oracle

Comment: What exactly do you get from `Debug.Print query1` (Of course after you did your `Replace()` )?

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit- Excel itself gets hanged